# accessing excel as database with jdbc

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

I have to design an application for accessing excel application as database. My problem is I have to create multiple connection for each transaction and if I miss any of closing it, the excel is not being update.

I want to design pattern where i am able to access the excel. Any one help me in designing a common pattern through which i wont be having problem. I want something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/jdbcutil/), but we are not able to use it to access excel.

Thanks in advance!

i have this method in utility class

```
static ResultSet  getExcelData(String filePath,String sqlQuery){
    ResultSet rs=null;


    try{
        conn    = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ="+filePath+";READONLY=false");
        stmt=    conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rs=stmt.executeQuery( sqlQuery ); 
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        // TODO: handle exception
    }finally{


    }
    return rs;

}
```

and i am calling it this way

```
ResultSet rs=JdbcUtil.getExcelData("D:\\AB_demo\\AB_demo\\test.xls", "Select max(int(ID)) from [MAIN$] where HEADER_IND is not Null AND int(ID)<"+excelId);
        int databaseId = 0;
        if(rs.next())
        {
            databaseId=rs.getInt(1);    
        }


        ResultSet rs1=JdbcUtil.getExcelData("D:\\AB_demo\\AB_demo\\test.xls", "SELECT * from [MAIN$]  where   id= '"+databaseId+"'or id='"+excelId+"'");
```

i am calling this method twice after which im updating the excel file by using

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

its returning the integer 1 but its not reflecting in excel.when i use process explorer the file is still in use.i need a design pattern or come code to overcome his kind of problem.

Comment: Why not use access as a database as excel isn't specifically meant to be used as a database

Comment: i am basically using it with testng where i have to read the class and the data in dictionary and run it through testng java code.and update the data if the test have passed or failed based on the result.i have http://code.google.com/p/excel-testng/ but my requirement is accessing excel as a database.

Comment: my requirement is using excel file

Comment: Firstly you need to update your post with what you have tried however, as another post has specified, excel is the second worst option for a database. raw csv being the first.

Comment: to access the file try. Control panel, administrative tools, System DSN and then setup the access file in there. Once setup in your java instead of using the path to the database just use DSN name that you setup in your dsn.

Comment: @liamsorsby.i am able to access the data but my concern is i have common method which returns resultset,i am getting data from this and passing data again to the comman method.after this process i am not able to update the file as it is in use

Comment: it will be as i bet the read statement is still in use. You may need to save the data. close the statement and then open up a new statement. Another method is check that the permissions on the file are not set to read only and the DSN in advanced are not set to read only. However, to give anymore help you really do need to be alot more specific with the errors and the code you are using. Please update your post

Comment: click edit on your post and put this into it

Answer (score 1):

I think more right way is generate Excel file from database. Otherwise you must create server side for ensure transactions and connections control.
Main problem of your task - Excel is

1. not database
2. not network database
   Other words you must use other tools, other approach for your tasks.