# accessing excel as database using jdbc on remote server

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

I want to access the excel file stored on the remote server through java application. I want to use jdbc for that. The apache poi is working but i want to do it using the jdbc for the desktop application.

Comment: Kindly refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478459/accessing-excel-as-database-with-jdbc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of achieving it would be to use [Fillo](http://www.codoid.com/products/view/2/29).

> Fillo is an Excel API for Java and you can query xls & xlsx files.
>   Now, it supports SELECT, UPDATE & INSERT queries with or without WHERE
>   clause.

The sample code will look something like this.

```
Fillo fillo=new Fillo();
Connection connection=fillo.getConnection("C:\\Test.xlsx");
String strQuery="Select * from Sheet1 where ID=100 and name='John'";
Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);

while(recordset.next()){
    System.out.println(recordset.getField("Details"));
}

recordset.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: @Harshal: you can mount the folder, on the network and share the excel file to make it accessible to the server.